# Margin totals in xtabs

Tags: r

If you have 2 cross classifying variables you can use `rowSums` and `colSums` to produce margin totals on an `xtabs` output. But how can it be done if you have 3 classifying variables (ie margin totals in each sub table)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aniko mentioned this in a comment, but it was never provided as an answer.

I found this independently and then noticed it was here in a comment, so credit to Aniko for getting it first.

`addmargins` is the answer:

> For a given table one can specify which of the classifying factors to
>   expand by one or more levels to hold margins to be calculated. One may
>   for example form sums and means over the first dimension and medians
>   over the second. The resulting table will then have two extra levels
>   for the first dimension and one extra level for the second. The
>   default is to sum over all margins in the table. Other possibilities
>   may give results that depend on the order in which the margins are
>   computed. This is flagged in the printed output from the function.

Answer (score 5):

The general approach is to use the `apply` function, but specifically for totals the `margin.table` function might be more convenient:

```
#create 3 factors
a <- gl(2,4, length=20)
b <- gl(3,2, length=20)
d <- gl(4,2, length=20)
# table
tt <- xtabs(~a+b+d)

# marginal sums
margin.table(tt, 1)
apply(tt, 1, sum)  #same answer

#multi-way margins
margin.table(tt, 1:2)
apply(tt, 1:2, sum)  #same answer
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are not tied to xtabs, the Deducer package has some nice functions for contingency tables:

```
> a <- gl(2,4, length=20)
> b <- gl(3,2, length=20)
> d <- rnorm(20)>0
> dat <- data.frame(a,b,d)
> tables<-contingency.tables(
+ row.vars=a,
+ col.vars=b,
+ stratum.var=d,data=dat)
> tables
================================================================================

               ==================================================               
                      ========== Table: a by b ==========                      

                       | -- Stratum = FALSE --
                       | b 
                     a |        1  |        2  |        3  | Row Total | 
-----------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           1  Count    |        2  |        2  |        1  |        5  | 
              Row %    |   40.000% |   40.000% |   20.000% |   55.556% | 
              Column % |   40.000% |  100.000% |   50.000% |           | 
              Total %  |   22.222% |   22.222% |   11.111% |           | 
-----------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           2  Count    |        3  |        0  |        1  |        4  | 
              Row %    |   75.000% |    0.000% |   25.000% |   44.444% | 
              Column % |   60.000% |    0.000% |   50.000% |           | 
              Total %  |   33.333% |    0.000% |   11.111% |           | 
-----------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
          Column Total |        5  |        2  |        2  |        9  | 
              Column % |   55.556% |   22.222% |   22.222% |           | 

                       | -- Stratum = TRUE --
                       | b 
                     a |        1  |        2  |        3  | Row Total | 
-----------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           1  Count    |        2  |        2  |        3  |        7  | 
              Row %    |   28.571% |   28.571% |   42.857% |   63.636% | 
              Column % |   66.667% |   50.000% |   75.000% |           | 
              Total %  |   18.182% |   18.182% |   27.273% |           | 
-----------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           2  Count    |        1  |        2  |        1  |        4  | 
              Row %    |   25.000% |   50.000% |   25.000% |   36.364% | 
              Column % |   33.333% |   50.000% |   25.000% |           | 
              Total %  |    9.091% |   18.182% |    9.091% |           | 
-----------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
          Column Total |        3  |        4  |        4  |       11  | 
              Column % |   27.273% |   36.364% |   36.364% |           | 


================================================================================
```

Answer (score 2):

(if I understand correctly) You could use ddply:

```
ff <- data.frame(f1=c("a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"), f2=c("p", "p", "p", "q", "q", "q", "q"), f3=c("x","x","x","x","y", "y", "y"), val=c(1:7)) 

ddply(ff, .(f1), numcolwise(sum))
ddply(ff, .(f2), numcolwise(sum))
ddply(ff, .(f3), numcolwise(sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

Comments aren't working above. Thanks for the answers, but they didn't do what I was expecting - individual totals in each subgrouping.

After a little digging around, I found that the xtabs output in this case is a 3 dimensional array, and wrote the following function to achieve my desired result (note its incomplete, but works for column totals so far):

```
xtabTotals <- function(tabs,margin=1)
# takes a 3 dimensional xtabs array and performs margin total on each sub table
# only doing column margins so far
{
    out <- array(0,dim(tabs)+c(1,0,0))
    dnout <- dimnames(tabs)
    dnout[[1]] <- c(dnout[[1]],"Total")
    dimnames(out) <- dnout

    for (i in 1:dim(tabs)[3])
    {
        out[,,i] <- rbind(tabs[,,i],colSums(tabs[,,i]))
    }
    out
}
```

Comment: I clearly did not understand what you wanted, and I still don't even looking at your function. Perhaps you are looking for `addmargins`?